# Going in reverse with RegEx

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a Python script and I need to extract two pieces of information from the following text:

> The user XXXXXXXX (XXXXXXX@XXXXXX.com) was involved in an impossible travel incident. The user connected from two countries within 102 minutes, from these IP addresses: Country1 (111.111.111.111) and Country2 (222.222.222.222). Another irrelevant staff...

I need "Country1" and "Country2". I already extracted the IPs so I can look for them in my expression.

With this regex:  `(?> )(.*)(?= \(111\.111\.111\.111)`

I take all this:

> The user XXXXXXXX (XXXXXXX@XXXXXX.com) was involved in an impossible travel incident. The user connected from two countries within 102 minutes, from these IP addresses: Country1

Is there a way to take all the characters going backward and make it stop at the first space, to take just "**Country1**" ?

Or does anyone knows a better way to extract "**Country1**" and  "**Country2**" with a regex or directly with Python?

Comment: Change `.*` to `\S*` to match anything except whitespace.

Comment: Maybe `\w+(?=\s*\(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}\))` or `\S+(?=\s*\(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}\))`? `\(111\.111\.111\.111` will only match static text.

Comment: `Is there a way to take all the characters going backward and make it stop at the first space` Aren't some country names composed of multiple words? e.g. Saudi Arabia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your message pattern is always the same you can get the countries like this using Python:

```
your_string = 'The user XXXXXXXX (XXXXXXX@XXXXXX.com) ...'
your_string = your_string.split(': ')[1].split(' and ')
first_country = your_string[0].split(' (')[0]
second_country = your_string[1].split(' (')[0]
```

Comment: Thank you !! This solution actally solved another problem that @Nick ODell raised that I didn't think about, take the country even when it has multiple words.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\S+(?=\s*\(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nkoP6i/2).

*Details*:

- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars
- `(?=\s*\(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}\))` - a positive lookahead that requires the following pattern to appear immediately at the right of the current location:

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}` - one to three digits and then three repetitions of `.` and one to three digits
  - `\)` - a `)` char.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples please try following regex, written and tested in Python3. I am using Python3's `re` library and its [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=findall#re.findall) module here.

```py
import re

var="""...""" ##Place your value here.

re.findall(r'(\S+)\s\((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\)',var)
['Country1', 'Country2']
```

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/PwDedY/1) for above used regex.